# Add a class only if the other class doesn't exist

Tags: javascript

I have this javascript here

```
  if (stepNumber < $steps.length) {
    $($steps[stepNumber + 1]).addClass('--active');
  }
```

However i Don't want to have the class to be added if --complete is already on it.

Could someone point me in the right direction? I was thinking it would be `if (!.--complete)` or something along those lines?

Comment: It's as easy as `$($steps[stepNumber + 1]).not('.--complete').addClass('--active');`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check if it has that class with `#hasClass()`:

```
if (stepNumber < $steps.length) {
    var $step = $($steps[stepNumber + 1]);
    if (!$step.hasClass('--complete')) {
        $step.addClass('--active');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're doing something you will later regret.  You're using your UI decorations as a data source for reference, which could make a mess later for synchronizing your UI with your data if you continue this practice.

I suggest you use a data source to track the empirical state of the controls to determine whether complete or active and always draw your control set update from data.  This data set could be local or remote.

Separating this out ensures a limited number of coding touch points when you need to make modifications in the future.  Further, if you abstract all UI updates into one function that always sits between your data and your display and has the sole responsibility for updating the display based on changes to data, you'll have only one place to go back to when you need to add a third or fourth class.